# Python Module for rich gui interfaces

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Was just wondering what all python modules are available for rich(and easy to build :) ) gui interfaces. I am aware of Tkinter and Pwm extension but any other reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: this is a dupe of many, many questions here on SO. try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115495/is-python-any-good-for-gui-development or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962194/python-attractive-clean-packagable-windows-gui-library or just search for "python gui" to get enough reading material to last you a few hours

Answer (score 6):

The following list comes from Mark Lutz's [*Programming Python*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596158106) 4th edition:

- [tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) and extensions: [Pmw](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/), [Tix](http://tix.sourceforge.net/), and [ttk](http://code.google.com/p/python-ttk/)
- [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/): "A Python interface for the open source wxWidgets." This is what we use at our company for any Python desktop GUIs.
- [PyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt)
- [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/)
- Jython
- IronPython
- PythonCard
- [Dabo](http://dabodev.com/): Dabo looks pretty interesting. Check out Ed Leafe's and Paul McNett's presentation from PyCon 2010: [Creating Rich Client Applications in Dabo](http://python.mirocommunity.org/video/1624/pycon-2010-creating-rich-clien).

Other options not listed in [*Programming Python*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596158106) include:

- [TraitsGUI](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits_gui/): Corran Webster gave a [Traits Tutorial](http://pycon.blip.tv/file/3633134/) at PyCon 2010.

Comment: I'd add a +1 vote for wxPython. I was using it quite awhile ago, but was pretty happy with it. Hope it got even better

Comment: @maksymko: wxPython is the only Python GUI that we use at our company.

Answer (score 3):

You can give Camelot a try. Its a RAD framework using Python, Sqlalchemy and Qt to build rich desktop applications.

http://www.python-camelot.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is also [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/), which is pretty powerful. I was struggling with it at the beginning, but I'm getting more and more comfortable with it.

Answer (score 0):

PySide + QML may also be a good choice. Some examples are available [here](http://thpmaemo.blogspot.com/2010/12/pysideqml-tutorials-online-workshop.html)